# How can I read out the data from the dictionary?

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a plist that looks like this:

```
<dict>
<key>Aaron</key>
<dict>
    <key>number</key>
    <string>1234</string>
    <key>country</key>
    <string>Spanien</string>
    <key>year</key>
    <string>1989</string>
</dict>
<key>Abagail</key>
<dict>
    <key>number</key>
    <string>1234</string>
    <key>country</key>
    <string>Frankrike</string>
    <key>year</key>
    <string>2001</string>
</dict>
<key>Abbey</key>
<dict>
    <key>number</key>
    <string>1289</string>
    <key>country</key>
    <string>Tyskland</string>
    <key>year</key>
    <string>2009</string>
</dict>
```

With this code i get the key of each object:

```
NSLog(@"test %@", [dict objectForKey:key2]);
```

How can I get the string values of each object. My viewdidload looks like this

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vin"
                                                 ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

self.allNames = dict;

NSString *key2 = viewTitle;

NSLog(@"test %@", [dict objectForKey:key2]);
```

Comment: This question is not clear, are you actually succeeding in reading the file or not?

Comment: blasted subway tunnels made me double comment.

Comment: Yes, I can read out the file.

Comment: In that case, MrTJ's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the plist above, you can get access for example to the value of `country`:

```
NSDictionary* record2 = (NSDictionary*)[dict objectForKey:key2];
NSString* country = (NSString*)[record2 objectForKey:@"country"];
```

Comment: what is `key2` here ? index ?

Comment: It is a key in the top level dictionary. Keys are similar concept for dictionaries as indices for arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like XML see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML there are quite a few parses for it and I bet iDevices have one in their SDK